# #1235 - This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' in MySQL

Tags: sql, subquery, mariadb, limit

This is my MySQL query:

```
select t.*
from hr_pangkat t
where t.oID >= any (select t2.oID
                   from hr_pangkat t2
                   where t2.pegawaiID = t.pegawaiID
                   order by t2.oID asc
                   offset 1 limit 1
                  );
```

and it shows error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'offset 1 limit 1
                  ) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 7
```

and if i delete the offset, it still show error like this:

```
#1235 - This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

How to fix it?

I'm using **MySQL version 5.6**

Comment: However the system thinks you are using `MariaDB`

Comment: I fixed the tags. Removed [tag:mysql] and replaced it with [tag:mariadb]. There's no way you are using MySQL 5.6 if the error tells you it's MariaDB. Maybe you are using MySQL 5.6 _client_ to connect to MariaDB _server_. The syntax error is determined by the server, so it's irrelevant what client version you use.

Answer (score 2):

The `any` is not needed:

```
select t.*
from hr_pangkat t
where t.oID >= (select t2.oID
                from hr_pangkat t2
                where t2.pegawaiID = t.pegawaiID
                order by t2.oID asc
                offset 1 limit 1
               );
```

However, this fails if there is only one row.  So, you can add:

```
select t.*
from hr_pangkat t
where t.oID >= coalesce( (select t2.oID
                          from hr_pangkat t2
                          where t2.pegawaiID = t.pegawaiID
                          order by t2.oID asc
                          offset 1 limit 1
                         ), t.oID
                       );
```